# nginx refuses connection to localhost:80

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, web-server, nginx

I'm setting up nginx on a Raspberry Pi 4 under Raspbian 11 (Bullseye) but it's refusing connections on http://localhost:80/

```
This site can't be reached
127.0.0.1 refused to connect
```

However, it looks like it's running as `sudo systemctl status nginx` returns...

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-12-24 15:48:20 PST; 1h 19min ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 4326 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 4327 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 4328 (nginx)
      Tasks: 5 (limit: 4915)
        CPU: 88ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
             ├─4328 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
             ├─4329 nginx: worker process
             ├─4330 nginx: worker process
             ├─4331 nginx: worker process
             └─4332 nginx: worker process

Dec 24 15:48:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 24 15:48:20 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

This is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
#
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Here's my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/
# https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/
# https://wiki.debian.org/Nginx/DirectoryStructure
#
# In most cases, administrators will remove this file from sites-enabled/ and
# leave it as reference inside of sites-available where it will continue to be
# updated by the nginx packaging team.
#
# This file will automatically load configuration files provided by other
# applications, such as Drupal or Wordpress. These applications will be made
# available underneath a path with that package name, such as /drupal8.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    #root /var/www/html;
    root /home/scoreboard/wwwroot;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #   include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Here is the directory listing for `/home/scoreboard/wwwroot`

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 scoreboard scoreboard 4096 Dec 24 14:54 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 scoreboard scoreboard 4096 Dec 24 14:36 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 scoreboard scoreboard  180 Dec 24 14:54 index.html
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Update 1**

Using `sudo lsof -i :80 -s TCP:LISTEN` and `sudo lsof -i :443 -s TCP:LISTEN` doesn't show any listeners. I suspected this was the case with port 80 and I'm not surprised by the lack of listening on 443, the SSL port.

**Update 2**

Executing `cat /var/log/nginx/error.log' shows that the error log is empty.

**Update 3**

I tried adding explicit bindings to the loopback address and Pi's static IP to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`...

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        # New bindings 
        listen 127.0.0.1:80;
        listen 192.168.4.1:80;

        # ...the file continues...
```

**Update 4**

Running `sudo netstat -anp` and it listed all of the ports listening. It's a big list and I culled it down to just the `Java` app that's running on port 8000 and `nginx`.

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      672/java

Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name     Path
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     132043   24462/nginx: master
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     132044   24462/nginx: master
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     132041   24462/nginx: master
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     132046   24462/nginx: master
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     132042   24462/nginx: master
```

But it's still not listening.

Comment: This telling you that" This site can't be reached". The servers is not on that time or no longer, etc

Comment: @toyotaSupra While "the server is not on" may be a cause of a connection refused error, the error means that there is nothing listening on the port specified, port 80 in this case. `systemctl status` tells me the server is running and not reporting any errors.

Comment: which device are you using to reach http://localhost:80/ ?

Comment: @jsotola I"m making the page request from the Pi I'm setting up nginx on. To be thorough, I connected my Windows laptop to the same network as the Pi and made the request to to the Pi's static IP, http://192.168.4.1:80 and got the same result. Not a big surprise given that lsof isn't reporting any listeners on port 80.

Comment: What does `sudo netstat -anp` show?  Do you see nginx listening on port 80 or 443.  Post your results here.

Comment: @HeatfanJohn See update 4.

Comment: Ugh. How is a question abpout setting up NGINX on a Raspberry Pi 4 under Raspbian not on topic for the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange?

Comment: Because tacking "on a Raspberry Pi" on the end of a question does not make it a question about the Raspberry Pi.  Consider: Otherwise, since you can write and run code on a Pi in just about every contemporary programming language, you could then ask just about any question about basic (or advanced, or whatever) programming here.  You could take the vast majority of the 23+ million questions on Stack Overflow, literally cut n' paste them here and add "on a Raspberry Pi".  But that is not the point of having a separate exchange for Raspberry Pi **specific** questions.

Comment: There is nothing here that makes this question Pi **specific**.   This is not just about hassling people because I love abusing power, it is for your benefit as well.  If you had asked this on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), [Super User](http://superuser.com/), or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), you probably would have had a solution within hours.  Instead, you have had no attempts at an answer after 3 days. By analogy, if you were doing this on a Dell laptop, would your first choice of forums be one for Dell users?  Or does the brand of hardware actually not matter?

Comment: @goldilocks One, this isn't a programming question. It's a question about getting a specific service to run on a Raspberry Pi where it is currently failing. In my work in trying to resolve this issue issue, I've already found differences in Linux variations from even the the NGINX resources pages (ie trouble shooting options that aren't available in Raspain Bullseye for example.) This question is literally about a Raspberry Pi implementation.

Comment: @goldilocks That's a bad analogy. Dell Laptops don't come with their own specific flavor of Windows that deviates from the gold release from Microsoft.

Comment: The extent to which RpiOS differs from the Debian base is trivial, and even the difference between major linux distros is not much with regard to stuff like this -- it will be a  matter of default configuration files and what x.x.x version of nginx is packaged; except possibly for security patches, it is exactly the same software on all of them.   There is no "Raspberry Pi" specific implementation of nginx any more than there is a "Dell laptop" specific implementation of nginx.

Comment: ...Neither is there an RpiOS specific implementation.  If you can somehow make this question read as about something that could only happen on a Pi, then great, otherwise you are wasting your time.   That said, I am not an nginx user, but at a glance I notice there is a distinction between the `sites-enabled` and `sites-available` directories: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19084424/1151724 You look to have included one in the `http { }` block of nginx.conf, but then defined a site in the other.